# How come the URL of my new web application doesn't resolve?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

So, I created a new SharePoint Web Application (and a Site Collection to go with it) in SharePoint Foundation 2010.  When I navigate to the URL I specified, I get a vanilla "This page can't be displayed" error.  However, when I Browse the site in IIS, it takes me to http://localhost:18617/SitePages/Home.aspx, and the new site does come up... with the name that I specified and everything else.

The other site I had created when I set up the farm DOES come up the way it should.  How come this new site doesn't resolve when I plug http://thenewsite/ into the browser?  Did I miss a step?

Comment: You need to extend your web application http://localhost:18617 and alias it http://thenewsite/

Comment: Lemme axe you this: How does one do that?

Comment: Well, I found an option in Central Admin to "Extend" the Web App.  In the URL section, it was set to *[localmachine]*:12345.  I updated it to the URL I want, and got an error.  When I went back to the Extend option, it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  So, now I can't get back into the Extend settings.  I really hate SharePoint.

Comment: Are you using DNS? Did you updated the AAM? Also did you updated you iis bindings

Comment: I don't know what an AAM is.  I also don't know what IIS bindings are.  One would think that SharePoint would just do all that when the site is created.

Answer (score 0):

Either a DNS issue, please check if

```
ping thenewsite
```

works from a command prompt on another workstation. Or it may be the case that IIS is configured to accept web requests by headers (url names) and it is not recognizing thenewsite to be related to the site.

Comment: I'm just trying to access the site from the workstation that the site was created on.  So, not even over a network. (hence the "localhost" part of the url mentioned above).  that said, I can't ping it.  "Ping request could not find host thenewsite."

Comment: If I understand correctly if you type into your browser http://localhost:18617/SitePages/Home.aspx it works, if you type http://thenewsite it doesn't. I'd then expect ping localhost to work, ping thenewsite to fail. This shows that thenewsite needs to be added to the DNS to be resolved correctly. If it is already on DNS, than the servers DNS settings might require having a look at.

Comment: Adding to the DNS via the Hosts file?  Why doesn't SharePoint do that automatically when it creates the site?

Comment: Host file solves you problem only on the workstation / server in question, good for testing. But actually you need to ask your IT (or other relevant department) to add it to your organisation's DNS server. It is a separate service doing name resolution. Beyond SharePoint's remit really.